# Logging in I get the error: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property

Tags: users

When I log into my site I get the error: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7721 of /home/sites/mysiteurl.com/includes/common.inc).

In a new tab if I then revisit the site I am now logged in. So the error does not stop the log in process from occurring, but I do need to stop it from happening so that people can log in smoothly.

Googling around the issue I can see people discussing EntityMalformedException with reference to a lot of different problems. It is hard for me to find information on how this problem might relate to logging in as adding 'logging in' to the search still returns lots of pages that have a 'log in' option.

I wish I could tell you the actions i took just before the error started occurring, but I have only just noticed it, and it has been quite a while since I worked on the site.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a node with a missing or obsolete content type...a query like `SELECT * FROM node WHERE type NOT IN (SELECT type FROM node_type)` might show a culprit

Comment: Nice idea Clive, but that query didn't return any results. So I think it might be something else. Plus I don't recall deleting any content types. I'd appreciate any other ideas you have.